# Plotting heatmap of a correlation matrix using Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I would like to plot a heatmap of the following kind of matrix.

[Matrix to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GEwR.png)

The final output should look like this: [Expected output style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUU4d.png)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `heatmap` function from a plotting package, e.g., Plots.jl?

```
julia> using Plots, LinearAlgebra

julia> M = min.(1.0, Matrix(Symmetric(rand(5,5) + I)))
5×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0        0.737985  0.0273955  0.199343  0.0553962
 0.737985   1.0       0.604142   0.576031  0.785242
 0.0273955  0.604142  1.0        0.854256  0.389215
 0.199343   0.576031  0.854256   1.0       0.327517
 0.0553962  0.785242  0.389215   0.327517  1.0

julia> heatmap(M, yflip=true)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, Benoit! I was trying to do this using a data frame -I should have converted it to a matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
using PlotlyJS
z = convert(Matrix{Float64}, z)
plot( heatmap(z=z))
```